# Running tasks in parallel

Tags: c#, async-await

I've just started writing asynchronous methods for the first time having watched some tutorials.

I have a method where I run two tasks in parallel (`notifySales, insertDownload`):

```
Task insertDownload = _downloadService.InsertDownloadRequestAsync(model, Request.UserAgent);

if (product.NotifySalesByEmail)
{
    Task notifySales = _downloadService.EmailDownloadRequestAsync(model);
    await Task.WhenAll(insertDownload, notifySales);
}
else
{
    await insertDownload;
}
```

As you can see, the task `notifySales` only gets run if `product.NotifySalesByEmail` is true. This task, as well as task `insertDownload` can be run in parallel.

I'm not sure I like the way in which I have said 'if true await both else just await one'.

Would a better way to be to create a `Task[]` array, add the tasks that are required to run and then await the array?

Comment: Do you actually need to wait on completion?

Comment: Can you add more context? At the moment it's hard to tell if that's the good way to proceed. Though it's not bad

Comment: @ratchetfreak In fact I don't. However, if I do not await the notifySales task then I get the following exception: "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as it stands doesn't read well. And your text is also slightly confusing. I do believe I would rework the code to something along these lines:

- Initialize an array of tasks
- Add each task to array, with necessary conditions if needed
- Await execution of all tasks

This would make for your code to handle extra tasks better, it would clear up the confusion on which tasks actually gets executed, and finally all tasks can be executed in parallell however the compiler feels like doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Just taking into account the code that's present in the question here (and not considering a possible extension scenario in more tasks): 
Being that you have to wait for `insertDownload` anyway, I'd suggest to rewrite the code in the following way:

```
Task insertDownload = _downloadService.InsertDownloadRequestAsync(model, Request.UserAgent);

if (product.NotifySalesByEmail)
{
    await _downloadService.EmailDownloadRequestAsync(model);
}

await insertDownload;
```

Comment: First of all I would just like to say that I am very new to writing asynchronous code so please bear with me. `InsertDownloadRequestAsync` and `EmailDownloadRequestAsync` are two independent tasks that have no effect on each other, meaning they can be run in parallel. If I await `EmailDownloadRequestAsync` then does this mean `InsertDownloadRequestAsync` cannot start running? Or has `InsertDownloadRequestAsync` started running as soon as it has been assigned to `Task insertDownload` ?

Comment: @JakkyD maybe I sounded too inquisitive, sorry for that (I tend to appear that way when writing). That being said, in this particular case there's no big difference if you wait for one task to finish and then for the other. Seeing that you used `await` I guess the method is marked as `async` so this would be the best way IMO. In the general case of more tasks I'd suggest you to go with @holroy's approach.

Comment: @JakkyD `await` does not start `Task`s, they start as soon as you call the method that returns it. So this answer will execute the two `Task`s in parallel.